# Android audio record external jack

Tags: android, audio, external, record

I would like to record the sound of the jack entry of my android phone. I've been searching about the Audio Capture class in Android, and i've found this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html

In the settings of this class, there are many options to choose the rec default mic, as this:

Set the audio source using MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(). You will probably want to use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC.

What should I use to get the sound of the jack entry? Is there any example?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you provided is the correct one.

Calling mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC) (assuming the correct initialization of MediaRecorder as described here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html -> Capturing Videos) will behave like this:

When you launch your app and start recording without any Jacks connected, phone's default microphones will be used. As soon as Jack microphone pin has detected a microphone connected, the system will use the Jack mic pin as an audio imput. Hovewer, you need to know that even though the audio record will have two channels, they will be identical, as Jack microphone can only record mono stream.